# Derive Month of a Date Field to group by in Standard Summary Report

Tags: formula-field, date

I want to derive the month of a date field called MeetingDate__c. Purpose of this is to display all Meeting Records grouped by the derived month. I have created a formula field to derive the month from MeetingDate field but it doesnt save:-

```
MONTH(MeetingDate__c)
```

Error message display is :-

> Error: Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with
>   expected data type (Date).

Also is there a way that I can show the name of the month instead the number of the month? Ex: If derived month is 05 then display May ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is mainly because the `type of Formula` which you selected is `Date` and it should be `Number`. Change the formula return type to **Number**

Also, for getting the month name, change your formula to below

```
CASE(MONTH(MeetingDate__c),
1, "January",
2, "February",
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June",
7, "July",
8, "August",
9, "September",
10, "October",
11, "November",
12, "December",
"None")
```

This formula will first fetch the month from the date. Then using `Case` function, you can get the text value for the month. Also, now change the **type of the formula to Text**.

Refer [Functions in Formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=0)

Comment: I had to change return type to Text as it returns the name of the month. Apart from that the solution worked!